# Tried - gem install bundler on windows and received following error - Could not find a valid gem 'bundler' (>= 0)

Tags: rubygems

Full error message:
 Could not find a valid gem 'bundler' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)

I am not able to find adequate steps to fix this issue on Windows, can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

citing https://teamtreehouse.com/community/i-get-the-error-message-could-not-find-a-valid-gem-bundler-0-in-any-repository-how-can-i-fix-this-issue

You are behind a firewall or virus software. You need to switch to use http://rubygems.org,it will remove the https and add just the http if you are having this issue you will have to change it in your Gemfile of your test app as well or your server won't run